# Need to track from where content is being dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, dom-events

I have a div in one page that is being fulfilled with dynamic content, but after searching in EVERY corner of the website theme files, I wasn't able to find out which is the damn function that is being called to produce this content.

Searching through the files and folders for the div ID or class returns nothing, so I assume the content is being load dynamically from another dynamically loaded content and I need to know which.

Is there any way in JavaScript that I can seek from where dynamic content is being loaded? Using the console, for example.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried

Comment: I'd check the browser's devtools Network tab for requests to endpoints you don't recognize, and check the responses for the content.

Comment: Man, I just found out how to do this, just learned that you can use Ctrl + Shift + F from the console debugger and it will make a global search through the loaded files. And as I suspected, the function was being loaded from another dynamically loaded content.

Thank you so much for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that you can use Ctrl + Shift + F from the console debugger and it will make a global search through the loaded files. And as I suspected, the function was being loaded from another dynamically loaded content.

Thank you for the views, guys!

Comment: Since you were able to solve it yourself, consider marking your answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer